# Django + AWS: files not syncing to S3

Tags: python, django, file, amazon-s3, file-upload

I inherited a CMS system that was implemented using Django Suit. One of the forms is supposed to upload files to S3 but it's not happening (the files upload to the webserver - EC2, but not to S3).

What I determined so far:

1. The EC2 instance has full access to S3 (via a role)
2. The user set up in Django's config file has full access to S3
3. There is a CloudFront configured to point to the bucket, and it works when files are accessed via a URL. The configuration is working there
4. The previous developers used the following for handling the upload of files:

   DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'fallback_storage.storage.FallbackStorage'
   FALLBACK_STORAGES = (
       'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage',
       'main.custom_storages.MediaStorage'
   )

I looked into these 3 classes to see if I'm missing a configuration but everything looks good.

5. I'm not familiar with this way of syncing files between a web server and S3, so I may be missing something very obvious. Is there like a cron jon that needs to run in the background?
6. I found a blog post explaining how to use Django to upload files to S3 using FallbackStorage. That tutorial uses docker. In this case, docker is not used at all.

I'm lost at this point. There are thousands of classes spread across dozens of python libraries. It will take forever to do an exhaustive analysis of the code.

Comment: What is the fallback storage doing for your codebase? Is it necessary?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look at the FallbackStorage class, typically for file uploads to S3 this would be the storage class off S3BotoStorage with the proper `AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET`, `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` set.

```
stored = models.FileField(storage=S3BotoStorage(bucket=AWS_BUCKET), upload_to='blog-uploads')
```